# Flutter Calendar

Tags: flutter, dart

i tried to use syncfusion_flutter_calendar https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar
but it isn't work it always give me error 
BUILD FAILED in 48s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

is there any help or any one build syncfusion_flutter_calendar successfully please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To you this package you need licence and you have to provide licence key in main file as below.

```
  SyncfusionLicense.registerLicense('ADD YOUR LICENCE KEY HERE');
```

This message you can found in official [documention](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar#-readme-tab-).

> Disclaimer: This is a commercial package. To use this package, you
>   need to have either a Syncfusion commercial license or the Syncfusion
>   Community LICENSE. For more details, please check the LICENSE file